# jQuery Replacing Text

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace the Quantity's UOM text (Example: EA in the screenshot) with whatever label's UOM is selected (Example: EA or CS6 in the screenshot).

[image]

Here's the HTML code:

```
<span class="uomPrice">
   <input type="radio" id="uom-0" name="adduom0" value="0">&nbsp;<label for="uom-0">$81.15&nbsp;EA</label><br>
   <input type="radio" id="uom-1" name="adduom0" value="1">&nbsp;<label for="uom-1">$486.89&nbsp;CS6</label>
</span>

<span class="qty-uom">EA</span>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$('.uomPrice label').click(function(e){
   var text = $(e.target).text();
   var selectedUom = text.substring(text.indexOf('\xa0') +1).toString(); // grabs uom after a non-breaking space
   var qtyUom = $('.qty-uom').text();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To replace the text of something use `$(selector).text(replacement)`

Comment: `substring()` always returns a string, you don't need `.toStringz()`.

Comment: I originally tried adding this line in the JS - $(qtyUom).text(selectedUom); - but that doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your click handler is on the label, not the radio button. Are you sure you were clicking on the correct thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.text()` with an argument to replace the text.

```js
$('.uomPrice label').click(function(e) {
  var text = $(e.target).text();
  var selectedUom = text.substring(text.indexOf('\xa0') + 1).toString(); // grabs uom after a non-breaking space
  $('.qty-uom').text(selectedUom);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="uomPrice">
   <input type="radio" id="uom-0" name="adduom0" value="0">&nbsp;<label for="uom-0">$81.15&nbsp;EA</label><br>
   <input type="radio" id="uom-1" name="adduom0" value="1">&nbsp;<label for="uom-1">$486.89&nbsp;CS6</label>
</span>
<br>
<span class="qty-uom">EA</span>
```

Note that to make this work you have to click on the label, not the radio button.

Comment: This works! What if I wanted to be able to click the input or the label?

Comment: Then you should use `$(".uumPrice :radio")` as the selector, and use `$(this).next("label").text()` to get the text of the label.